# Reflection of a plane on a plane

Tags: vectors, 3d

> How to find the reflection of the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ in the plane
>   $a'x+b'y+c'z+d'=0$?

I can't really think of a method of for doing so.
I do know how to reflect a line on a plane though.That could be done just by finding the projection of any two points on the line onto the plane.And then probably mid-point theorem.

But how do I reflect a plane on  a plane?

Comment: One method assuming you know how to reflect a *point* across a plane: Find three noncollinear points on the plane and reflect them.  Then those three points will determine the reflection.

Comment: Its not that easy to find three points in this case as the coefficients are a,b,c,d @Bye_World

Comment: **Hint** One can use that the normal to the reflection of the plane is the reflection of the normal to the plane, and this reflection is the Householder transformation determined by the normal of the reflecting plane.

Comment: Householder transformation :-P never heard of it @Travis....yes that is probably a good idea..reflecting the normal :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write the plane in point-normal form, then reflect the point and the normal.

Specifically, suppose we are given the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Let $\mathbf{N} = (a,b,c)$, let $k = \mathbf{N} \cdot \mathbf{N} = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, and let 
$\mathbf{P} = \frac{-d\mathbf{N}}{k}$. Then $\mathbf{N} \cdot \mathbf{P} = -d$, and so

\begin{align}
&ax+by+cz+d=0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad &\mathbf{N} \cdot \mathbf{X} + d =0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad &\mathbf{N} \cdot (\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{P}) = 0 \\
\end{align}
So the plane passes through the point  $\mathbf{P}$ and has normal vector $\mathbf{N}$. Reflect $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{N}$ through the other plane to get a reflected point $\mathbf{P}'$ and a reflected normal vector $\mathbf{N}'$. The equation of the reflected plane is then $\mathbf{N'} \cdot (\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{P'}) = 0$.